# Live update sharepoint, when Excel Desktop has been modified

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, excel-online

So I have created a table in Excel Desktop. This Excel document should be available for everyone at my department, hence I have uploaded this Excel document to a shared SharePoint.

However, if I make a change in Excel Desktop, this will not be visible in SharePoint.

Is there any way to live update SharePoint from Excel Desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, there is no option to live update SharePoint excel file with desktop excel file.

As a workaround, you could use OneDrive to sync file after making changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the file from SharePoint instead of the local file.